# Sign a file with a certificate stored in Microsoft store

Tags: delphi, certificate

I would like to sign a file using the certificate that is stored in the Microsoft store, searched everywhere for some info or samples but couldn't find anything... My app currently can sign a file using the .pfx file but that is not the best solution since it exports the private key as well. Does anyone have any suggestions or tips by any chance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For 32 bit application, you may use [capicom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPICOM). Or as Microsoft suggests replacing CAPICOM with .NET Framework's X509 Cryptographic Classes and a number of other alternatives

Answer (score 1):

You could use Microsoft `signtool.exe`. it has command line options so you could call it with appropriate parameters from Delphi Application.

here are two links to its documentations:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool